# Firefox 11 and GeoLocation denial callback

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, geolocation

Things worked okay is Firefox 10.x but with the upgrade to Firefox 11 has thrown up a problem.

I use

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, failure)
```

but in FF11 the failure callback is not executed when the user denies sharing location by selecting "Not Now".

Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you sure it worked in FF10? Its marked as WONTFIX ; https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=675533

Comment: Hmm.. not sure, I may have upgraded from FF9 to FF11. Browser versions aren't what they used to be.. ;-)

Comment: @Srirangan the behavior of Firefox here has been the same all along.  "Not Now" is not a denial, it's a delay, so it doesn't fire the event.  This has been the case ever since the geolocation API landed in Gecko

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Okay, so the answer for now is: "Not possible, Firefox by design will not fire the failure event. Build your app around this constraint."

Answer (score 0):

Actually you get the error callback in Firefox ONLY if you click **Never share location**.

Because when you click **Not now** (or just close the popup), you can still click the location icon in address bar and allow it later.

(tested on FF28)

edit: here is a [demo](http://demo.chobits.ch/js/geolocation/) of how to detect location with special note for Firefox.