# Geolocation error callback in Google chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, geolocation

There is a strange bug (or feature?) in Google chrome browser (19.0.1084.56 m).
I'm trying to run the next JavaScript code on my page:

```
//...
function successCallback(position) {
    console.log('success');
}

function errorCallback(error) {
    console.log('error');
}

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    successCallback,
    errorCallback,
    {timeout: 1000});
//...
```

Browser ask me: "sitename wants to track your physical location [Allow] [Deny] ... Learn more [X]".

When I click on the Allow/Deny buttons the callback functions work fine. But when I click on the [X] button nothing happens :(
Is there any way to detect click on the [X]?

PS Looks like Firefox has the same feature [Firefox 11 and GeoLocation denial callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9769409/firefox-11-and-geolocation-denial-callback)

Answer (score 0):

I believe **Chrome doesn't have** callback for **ignore** option.

If I were you, I'd try to implement a timeout callback.

### Example code:

```
    _callback = false;
function successCallback(position) {
    _callback = true;
    console.log('success');
}

function errorCallback(error) {
     _callback = true; 
    console.log('error');
}

setTimeout(function(){if(!_callback)console.log('ignored')}, 10000); //chanche the timeout according your needs

navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
    successCallback,
    errorCallback,
    {timeout: 1000});
```